# How I can to see request headers of Flash in Extension Google Chrome?

Tags: flash, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, sniffing

I have extension for Chrome for seek a request and response headers. I am using *webRequest.onSendHeaders*, *webRequest.onHeadersReceived* and *webRequest.onCompleted* events for this. But i not see headers for load Flash. How i can do it?

Comment: Okay, i understand - the webRequest.onCompleted event bong, before begins Flash load. How i can wait to load all Flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash objects have `PercentLoaded()` method. Use it like this:

```
var testMovie = document.testMovie;

function waitUntilLoaded() 
{
    if(testMovie.PercentLoaded() == 100) {
        doSomething();//flash is loaded
    } else {
        setTimeout('waitUntilLoaded()',10);  
    }
}
waitUntilLoaded();
```

You will probably need a content script for this.

Comment: Does that approach allow looking at request headers? Because that's what the question is about...

Comment: Hm, you are right - I answered the question from comment: "How i can wait to load all Flash?"